# How to dynamicly update the date with the datetime module in python?

Tags: python, date, variables

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to create a program that automatically backs up my files.
I am using shutil to make archives and apscheduller to schedule the backup. I want to name my backup files by date, so I use datetime to get the current date and time. I have the script in the StartUp folder so that it runs on startup.

This is my code:

```
now = datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

backup_dir = r'path/to/backups/folder/' + date + 'docs_backup'
root_dir = r'C:/Users/user/'
base_dir = r'documents'

#This is to make the backup when the computer starts.
shutil.make_archive(
    backup_dir,
    'zip',
    root_dir,
    base_dir)

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', hours=1)
def zip_method():

     #Make the backup archive every one hour
     shutil.make_archive(
     backup_dir,
     'zip',
     root_dir,
     base_dir)
     print(date)
     print("I did a backup!")

sched.start()
```

The problem here is that the date variable is being declared once, so every hourly backup will have an outdated name. Is there any way I can assign a new value for the date variable each time I make a new archive?

Comment: make again a call to `datetime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")`

Comment: make the date generation + filenaming a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the file generation name into a function so that you can call it whenever/however you want as shown below.

```
ROOT_DIR = r'C:/Users/user/'
BASE_DIR = r'documents'
BACKUP_DIR = r'path/to/backups/folder/'
BACKUP_SUFFIX = 'docs_backup'


def make_backup_path():
    now = datetime.now()
    date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    backup_path = BACKUP_DIR + date + BACKUP_SUFFIX
    return backup_path


@sched.scheduled_job('interval', hours=1)
def zip_method():
     #Make the backup archive every one hour
     shutil.make_archive(
     make_backup_path(),
     'zip',
     ROOT_DIR,
     BASE_DIR)
     print(date)
     print("I did a backup!")

#This is to make the backup when the computer starts.
shutil.make_archive(
    make_backup_path(),
    'zip',
    ROOT_DIR,
    BASE_DIR)

sched.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking up local and global scope. If you put the part of the code that creates the date within the function, it will create a new one each time it is called.

```
#This is to make the backup when the computer starts.
shutil.make_archive(
    backup_dir,
    'zip',
    root_dir,
    base_dir)

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', hours=1)
def zip_method():
    # Establish the key variables
    now = datetime.now()
    date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    backup_dir = r'path/to/backups/folder/' + date + 'docs_backup'
    root_dir = r'C:/Users/user/'
    base_dir = r'documents'


     #Make the backup archive every one hour
     shutil.make_archive(
     backup_dir,
     'zip',
     root_dir,
     base_dir)
     print(date)
     print("I did a backup!")

sched.start()
```

Comment: for this to work you have to redefine several variables in the function scope as opposed to make the date generation and file path the output of a function

Comment: If I move the variables inside of the function, it will only make a backup every 1 hour and the first shutil.make_archive method won't work.

Comment: @gold_cy can you clarify what you mean?